# Можно ли изменять параметры сценария jmeter во время выполнения теста?

Tags: jmeter

Вопрос такой, можно ли изменять параметры сценария во время выполнения теста.
Интересует информация об изменении параметров типа "кол-во тредов, времени выполнения теста, шагов нагрузки" и т.д.
И если да, то как. Буду признателен за любую информацию или ссылки на полезные источники.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В текущей версии ([JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6)) параметры [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) читаются только один раз при старте.

Так что единственный способ повлиять на нагрузку это ограничить количество запросов в минуту, это можно сделать при помощи [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-throughput)

Если вы зададите количество запросов в минуту [функцией __P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) то значение этой функции можно будет менять в реальном времени и даже удаленно через [Beanshell Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server)

Остановить тест можно скриптом [shutdown.cmd](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/shutdown.cmd) или аналогом типа [telnet](https://docs.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/telnet)